# Join Multiple MySQL Queries Along With Grouping And Delete Record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following structure :

```
   ID Class Name   Email            Timestamp
    1 A     Ramesh ramesh@test.com  2014/03/07 17:29:34
    2 A     Ramesh ramesh@test.com  2014/03/12 17:29:34
    3 B     Kartik ramesh@test.com  2014/03/12 12:29:34
    4 B     Kartik ramesh@test.com  2014/03/17 12:29:34
    5 A     Ramesh newmail@test.com 2014/03/12 17:29:34
    6 C     Vinay  ramesh@test.com  2014/03/12 17:29:34
```

I'd like to select records having same name, class and email with more than one records and keep only the latest record and delete all others.

For example the output of the above table needs to be :

```
   ID Class Name   Email            Timestamp
    2 A     Ramesh ramesh@test.com  2014/03/12 17:29:34
    4 B     Kartik ramesh@test.com  2014/03/17 12:29:34
    5 A     Ramesh newmail@test.com 2014/03/12 17:29:34
    6 C     Vinay  ramesh@test.com  2014/03/12 17:29:34
```

I Tried the grouping statement but it doesn't works.

Comment: Are you aware that there is redundancy in this design?

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE x 
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT class,name,MAX(timestamp) max_timestamp FROM my_table GROUP BY class,name) y 
    ON y.class = x.class 
   AND y.name = x.name 
   AND y.max_timestamp = x.timestamp
 WHERE y.class IS NULL;
```